How to parameterize queries in c# when using Databricks?
I'm currently working on a C# ASP.NET service that interacts with a Databricks table, and I was trying to figure out a way to parameterize the SELECT queries made to that table. Here is an example of how the call is currently made:
var request = new DBRequestObject() // custom object for databricks requests
{
    warehouse_id = _warehouseId,
    catalog = _catalog,
    schema = _schema,
    format = _format,
    disposition = _dispositon,
    wait_timeout = "5s",
    statement = $"SELECT * from {_tableName} WHERE variableName = '{param.value}'"
};

var httpContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request, Formatting.Indented);
var content = new StringContent(httpContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpClient client = clientFactory.CreateClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

var response = await client.PostAsync(_redirectUrl, content);
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

I understand that this format leaves the request vulnerable to a possible SQL injection and would like to prevent that. I've read that parameterized queries can help, but I'm not sure how I would incorporate that here. I've seen the SqlCommand and SqlParameter objects used, but that seems like it only works for direct SQL connections.
Is there a way to incorporate this into the currently used method for querying, or would I need to rework how the call is made?
